# Regular Expression using JavaScript But No 0 or 00 or 000

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

My REGex is /^[a-z0-9]+$/i;
Got this from google.
i am using javascript validation in asp.net.
This is valid for alphanumeric field.
But here is one problem.. if i enter 0 or 00 or 000 or 0000 and so on then it's unable to prevent all these. So i want a REGex that will take alpha numeric character but won't allow 0 or 00 or 000 and so on. (In javascript only no jquery)

Comment: How about switching 0 to 1 in the current RegExp ..?

Comment: is `0` not alphanumeric or is it just not allowed in whatever input you are trying to use this for?

Comment: `/^0*[a-z1-9][a-z0-9]+$/`

Comment: is `0A` accepted?

Comment: @teemu same output.. if i enter only 0 then it unable to prevent

Comment: Do you want to remove 0s prefixes from input if the number is only integer?

Comment: @derek not working

Comment: @Saakey7 Oh oops, it should be `/^0*[a-z1-9][a-z0-9]*$/`

Comment: @gurvinder.. if i input "abc101" it should work or "AC180AC" it should work, "1056" should work, but if someone enters "0" or "00" or "000" and so on then it should show alert.....

Comment: what about `007` would this be a valid input?

Comment: @claies if i input "abc101" it should work or "AC180AC" it should work, "1056" should work, but if someone enters "0" or "00" or "000" and so on then it should show alert...

Comment: @thomas yes it will be a valid input

Comment: I don't get this. It's really unclear what you're asking for. Is all you want to do make sure your field doesn't contain all zero'es? Then simply `/[^0]/` will do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make slight adjustment in your regex

```
/^[a-z1-9][a-z0-9]*|0([a-z1-9][a-z0-9]*)$/i;
```

Explanation

- `[a-z1-9][a-z0-9]*` ensures that there is no 0 to begin with
- `0([A-Z1-9][A-Z0-9]*)` ensures that if there is a 0 to begin with then next character has to one of `[a-z1-9]`

**Edit**

As suggested by @Thomas `/^0*[a-z1-9][a-z0-9]*$/i` is more precise.

**Demo**

```js
var regex = /^0*[a-z1-9][a-z0-9]*$/i;

console.log( "0", !!"0".match( regex ) );
console.log( "00", !!"00".match( regex ) );
console.log( "000", !!"000".match( regex ) );
console.log( "0A", !!"0A".match( regex ) );
console.log( "AC180AC", !!"AC180AC".match( regex ) );
console.log( "1056", !!"1056".match( regex ) );
```

**Demo via input box**

```js
var regex = /^0*[a-z1-9][a-z0-9]*$/i;

document.querySelector( "button" ).addEventListener( "click", function(){
   var value = document.getElementById( "inputbox" ).value;
   var isValid = !!value.match( regex );
   isValid ? alert( "All Fine" ) : alert( "Error" );
})
```

```html
<input id="inputbox"><br><br><button>Check</button>
```

Comment: not working bro.. if i enter only 0 or 000 it unable to give alert.. it taking the input

Comment: @Saakey7 check the demo attached

Comment: how about `/^0*[a-z1-9][a-z0-9]*$/i`

Comment: @Thomas yes, this is more precise and will pass the scenarios given so far by OP.

Comment: /^[a-z1-9][a-z0-9]*|0([a-z1-9][a-z0-9]*)$/i; ---> not working.. if I enter 0 or 00 it's not showing alert

Comment: @Saakey7 Can you share what you have tried? Please make a fiddle or a working snippet.

Comment: @thomas /^0*[a-z1-9][a-z0-9]*$/i not working... if i enter 0 or 00 it accepting which should not

Comment: @Saakey7 demo shows that 00 is also false and hence not working. What do you mean by alert not showing?

Comment: if i enter only 0 or 00 it should show invalid input.. it should not grant the input...

Comment: if i give enter nothing then a lert coming.. if i enter 0 or 00 then also i want same alert to come..

Comment: But where did you entered the input. Please show that code.

Comment: But on what event are you invoking this code?

Comment: on button clientclick()

Comment: @gurvinder can u help?

Comment: Can you make a working fiddle to demonstrate your issue?

Comment: not possible bro now yaar :(

Comment: Then how do I help you? I have already shared a demo that displays false if the input is invalid.

Comment: @Saakey7 I have added a demo via input box as well.